# Conclude that $C([0,2 \pi], \mathbb{R})$ has infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

This question I saw first define an infinite set given by $\{ 1,\cos(x),\cos(2x),...,\sin(x),\sin(2x),... \}$

Then, it says to verify this set is orthogonal in the continuous functions $C([0,2 \pi], \mathbb{R})$ with the inner product defined as $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(x)g(x) dx$ and to find an orthonormal set from that one. From here no problem, the orthonormal set I found is $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}},\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}},\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sqrt{\pi}},...,\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}},\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sqrt{\pi}},...\}$.

My question is, how this helps to conclude that $C([0,2 \pi], \mathbb{R})$ has infinite dimension?

Comment: Orthogonal set of functions is linearly independent. Another collection of linearly indepedent set is the sequence of monomials $x^n.$ Also $(x+t)^{-1}$ for any $t>0$ is a family of linearly independent functions.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc this answers my question, I completely forgot it.

Comment: That set is orthogonal, but not orthonormal. You'll need something other than $2\pi$ and $\pi$ in the denominators. Probably $\sqrt{2\pi}$ and $\sqrt\pi.$

Comment: @ronno sorry, I'll do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite set is orthonormal, which implies that all of its vectors are linearly independent. With that in hand you conclude the vector space has infinite dimension.